# overuse of lists and string formating

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

This works, but is very un-Pythonic.  I am sure I am overusing string formatting and lists.  Can BeautifulSoup do it native?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xmlurl = "http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=33.37110&lon=-104.529&unit=0&lg=english&FcstType=dwml"
def get_forecast():
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(xmlurl))
        temps = soup.find_all("temperature")

        maxtemps = str(temps[0])
        maxlist = maxtemps.split('\n')
        maxvalue= str(maxlist[2]).lstrip()
        maxvalue = maxvalue.replace('<value>','')
        maxvalue = maxvalue.replace('</value>','')

        mintemps = str(temps[1])
        minlist = mintemps.split('\n')
        minvalue= str(minlist[2]).lstrip()
        minvalue = minvalue.replace('<value>','')
        minvalue = minvalue.replace('</value>','')

        print maxvalue
        print minvalue

if __name__ == '__main__':
        get_forecast()
```

temps comes back as a  addressable as a list:

```
[<temperature time-layout="k-p24h-n7-1" type="maximum" units="Fahrenheit">
      <name>Daily Maximum Temperature</name>
        <value>65</value>
        <value>75</value>
        <value>88</value>
        <value>92</value>
        <value>92</value>
        <value>89</value>
        <value>83</value>
    </temperature>, <temperature time-layout="k-p24h-n6-2" type="minimum" units="Fahrenheit">
      <name>Daily Minimum Temperature</name>
        <value>38</value>
        <value>47</value>
        <value>53</value>
        <value>55</value>
        <value>56</value>
        <value>56</value>
    </temperature>, <temperature time-layout="k-p1h-n1-1" type="apparent" units="Fahrenheit">   <value>53</value>       </temperature>]
```

I then proceed to manipulate it (poorly) until I beat it into submission....

I have read through so many pages of documentation on Python and BeautifulSoup that I can't see straight.  I'm sure BS4 can probably do this, but I haven't messed with XML enough to get the syntax right.

All I want is the first Daily Maximum Temperature (65) and the first Minimum Temperature (38).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than overusing, I believe you are ***overthinking*** your approach. See the following code:

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup

xml = """[<temperature time-layout="k-p24h-n7-1" type="maximum" units="Fahrenheit">
      <name>Daily Maximum Temperature</name>
        <value>65</value>
        <value>75</value>
        <value>88</value>
        <value>92</value>
        <value>92</value>
        <value>89</value>
        <value>83</value>
    </temperature>, <temperature time-layout="k-p24h-n6-2" type="minimum" units="Fahrenheit">
      <name>Daily Minimum Temperature</name>
        <value>38</value>
        <value>47</value>
        <value>53</value>
        <value>55</value>
        <value>56</value>
        <value>56</value>
    </temperature>, <temperature time-layout="k-p1h-n1-1" type="apparent" units="Fahrenheit">   <value>53</value>       </temperature>]"""

soup = bsoup(xml)
temps = soup.find_all("temperature")
max_temp = temps[0].find_all("value")[0].get_text()
print "Max temp: ", max_temp
min_temp = temps[1].find_all("value")[0].get_text()
print "Min temp: ", min_temp
```

**Result:**

```
Max temp:  65
Min temp:  38
[Finished in 0.6s]
```

You said you just want the first min and max temperatures, right? The way we did it is we create a soup first. Next, we search the soup for the `temperature` tags. We find two, one for the maximum and one for the minimum.

The third step -- finding the first of each -- is identical. First, we get the first `temperature` tag by using `temps[0]`. We then find all the elements with the `value` tag. The first element is returned by the `[0]` index. `get_text()` is just to get the inner text of the element. To get the first minimum temperature, we just change `temps[0]` to `temps[1]` so we can access the second `temperature` tag.

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Perfect.  And it makes sense.  Because temps is the soup, find_all and get_text work on it.....
Thank you.  I knew I was overdoing it and that it should be easy.  10 lines of ugly code reduced to two, and I can easily parse the following 5 days using values 1-5!

Comment: Actually, `temps` is just an element in the soup. However, any element you find in the soup, for as long as you don't use something like `.get_text()` on it, can still function as a soup on its own. Think of the multiple `find_all`s like draining the soup until only the pieces you want are left. :)

Comment: Well, it works during the day.  At night they reverse the order in the xml so that the minimums print before the maximums.  I'm assuming that I should be able to filter on the (type="xxx"), but I can't find the correct syntax  So how can I verify that temps[0] is in fact the maximum?
maxtemps = temps.find_all("maximum") ?

Comment: Found it!!!      min=soup.find_all(type="minimum") only returns the minimum, not both sets, so I can just pull specifically from it.  I guess I need to study XML more before trying to learn BS4!

Comment: @ChristopherMcDonald: Hey, sorry about late reply. Since the `type` is a unique identifier, you can use a simple `min=soup.find(type="minimum")` so you don't have to use `[0]` on it. Also, although `BS4` can parse XML, the best parsing library IMO for that is still `lxml`. Just food for thought. ;) Good luck!